# Target this function to a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to target this function to just the first div With the div id="africa".
css:

```
#africa{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color:#33CC33;}
#asia{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #FF6600;}
#australia{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #FF5050;}
#europe{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #666699;}
#north-america{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #CC0000;}
#south-america{width:16%; height: 20%; background-color: #003300;}
.names{width:16%;}
```

I want to target this section of the code to the first div which has the id "africa".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    });
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="names">Africa</button>
<div id="africa"></div>
<button class="names">Asia</button>
<div id="asia"></div>
<button class="names">Australia</button>
<div id="australia"></div>
<button class="names">Europe</button>
<div id="europe"></div>
<button class="names">North-america</button>
<div id="north-america"></div>
<button class="names">South-america</button>
<div id="south-america"></div>
```

Comment: Change `$("div")` to `$('#africa')` - You should read the [jQuery selectors documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the id selector.

```
$("#africa").animate({
  height: "toggle"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dnt need to do anything, just change div selector to id#Africa selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
 $("#africa").animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  });
 });
});
```